# Update Jaxb version in wsimport

Tags: web-services, soap, java-8, jaxb, wsimport

I am generating stub using wsimport of jdk 1.8. using

```
wsimport -d testOutput -p test.pkg1 -keep -extension -clientjar test3.jar allservices.wsdl
```

I need to use this stub in jar utility (webserviceUtility.jar) .This webserviceUtility.jar is deployed in webapplication using multiclassloader.
webapplication has its own jaxb jars (jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar jaxb-core-2.3.0.1.jar jaxb-impl-2.3.0.1.jar). It creates a conflict getting JaxBContext and I get databinding exception. Is there a way to provide jaxb version while creating stub using wsimport.